# Mapkit - How to get bounds coordinate in mapkit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, apple-maps

I am trying to show a map within the bounds of two coordinates. To show this, I have written this code.

```
    private func showMapWithinBounds() {
    let point1 = MKMapPoint(viewModel.boundsStart.location.coordinate)
    let point2 = MKMapPoint(viewModel.boundsEnd.location.coordinate)

    let mapRect = MKMapRect(x: fmin(point1.x, point2.x), y: fmin(point1.y, point2.y), width: fabs(point1.x - point2.x), height: fabs(point1.y-point2.y))
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, animated: true)
}
```

If I scroll that changes the bound latitude and longitude. So after I finish the scrolling, I want to get back that two positions' latitude and longitude which I failed.
I tried this but couldn't get back the new coordinates. I want the latitude and longitude of the mentioned position in the attached image. How can I get those coordinates?
[image]

Comment: You can you mapView.region.center to get the center coordinates, then from mapView.region.span you can get the points you need.

Comment: then I only get latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta but how to get latitude and longitude? @Asteroid

Comment: You have the center. Subtract half of the span's longitude and latitude from the center and it gives you the top left. Add half of the span's values to the center and it will give you the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that top left and bottom right corners are point1 and point2 respectively:

**Method 1**

Use MKMapView's *convert* method to convert a CGPoint on the view to a CLLocationCoordinate2D. If your mapView has a non-zero frame, it will be:

```
let point1 = mapView.frame.origin
let point2 = CGPoint(x: mapView.frame.maxX, y: mapView.frame.MaxY)

let point1Coord = mapView.convert(point1, toCoordinateFrom: yourReferenceView)
let point2Coord = mapView.convert(point2, toCoordinateFrom: yourReferenceView)
```

**Method 2**
Use *center* and *span* properties of the *mapView.region*:

```
let point1Coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapView.region.center.latitude + mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, longitude: mapView.region.center.longitude - mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2)

let point2Coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapView.region.center.latitude - mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, longitude: mapView.region.center.longitude + mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2)
```

Comment: thanks. I'm gonna try it now and let you know and also make it accepted answer if it works.

Comment: what do you mean by yourReferenceView? Is it mapView?

Comment: What is the frame for your mapView? It's just a matter of setting the right points.

Comment: I used method 2 and It works. thanks bro